# Locking in a factory method

Tags: c#, locking, factory-pattern

I am interfacing with a back-end system, where I must never ever have more than one open connection to a given object (identified by it's numeric ID), but different consumers may be opening and closing them independently of one another.

Roughly, I have a factory class fragment like this:

```
private Dictionary<ulong, IFoo> _openItems = new Dictionary<ulong, IFoo>();
private object _locker = new object();

public IFoo Open(ulong id)
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        if (!_openItems.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            _openItems[id] = _nativeResource.Open(id);
        }

        _openItems[id].RefCount++;

        return _openItems[id];
    }
}

public void Close(ulong id)
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        if (_openItems.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            _openItems[id].RefCount--;
            if (_openItems[id].RefCount == 0)
            {
                _nativeResource.Close(id);
                _openItems.Remove(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here is the problem.  In my case, _nativeResource.Open is *very* slow.  The locking in here is rather naive and can be very slow when there are a lot of different concurrent .Open calls, even though they are (most likely) referring to different ids and don't overlap, especially if they are not in the _openItems cache.

How do I structure the locking so that I am only preventing concurrent access *to a specific ID* and not to all callers?

Comment: You want to lock on an ID not on a global object _locker. Try to found an object that correspond to a single ID. Possibly build your own set of object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you may want to look into is a striped locking strategy.  The idea is that you share N locks for M items (possible ID's in your case), and choose a lock such that for any ID the lock chosen is always the same one.  The classic way of choosing locks for this technique is modulo division- simply divide M by N, take the remainder, and use the lock with that index:

```
// Assuming the allLocks class member is defined as follows:
private static AutoResetEvent[] allLocks = new AutoResetEvent[10];


// And initialized thus (in a static constructor):
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    allLocks[i] = new AutoResetEvent(true);
}


// Your method becomes
var lockIndex = id % allLocks.Length;
var lockToUse = allLocks[lockIndex];

// Wait for the lock to become free
lockToUse.WaitOne();
try {
    // At this point we have taken the lock

    // Do the work
} finally {
    lockToUse.Set();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be lockToUse.Reset() instead of .WaitOne()?

Comment: No.  `WaitOne` on an AutoResetEvent blocks until the Event becomes set (someone calls `Set` on it, or if this is the first time it is waited on, it was created with `true` passed to the constructor). As soon as the event is Set, the first thread to call WaitOne proceeds and (atomically) the event is reset and blocks all other Waiting threads.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I missed where you defaulted them all to true (in the constructor).  Thanks.  Going to try this out.

Comment: Make sure it's a static constructor, not an instance constructor!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .net 4, you could try the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) with something along these lines:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, IFoo> openItems = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, IFoo>();
private object locker = new object();

public IFoo Open(ulong id)
{
    var foo = this.openItems.GetOrAdd(id, x => nativeResource.Open(x));

    lock (this.locker)
    {
        foo.RefCount++;
    }

    return foo;
}

public void Close(ulong id)
{
    IFoo foo = null;

    if (this.openItems.TryGetValue(id, out foo))
    {
        lock (this.locker)
        {
            foo.RefCount--;

            if (foo.RefCount == 0)
            {
                if (this.openItems.TryRemove(id, out foo))
                {
                    this.nativeResource.Close(id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can see any glaring issues with that, please let me know!

Comment: The factory method in ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd is *not* thread safe. nativeResource.Open *can* execute *multiple* times using this implementation. [Check this](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2535774-additional-overload-to-system-concurrent-concurren)